# Prioritising UX Design Considerations

Tags: ux-designer, process, prioritization

Does anybody use "[Analytical Hierarchy Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_hierarchy_process)" to prioritise their UX design considerations?

I am very often been in the position where I am impounded by different criterias and alternatives for any given design quality like usability and easy of use.

Will be great help to know if anybody is taking advantage of any other statistical models for making a UX design decision.

Comment: Statistical model???  I personally use agile costing method.  It works great.

Comment: I really really hope not. Isn't the point of being a UX designer to use your experience and judgement.

Comment: @Novina, Interesting, I thought an agile costing method is more to do with translating story points to a rough estimate of  time and cost. I was looking ways to explain my design tradeoff analysis.

Comment: @dwkns, I thought the same until I came to know that we could use data science to measure user experience. People have been using statistics to make all sorts of marketing decisions. Agreed there is an additional overhead to the designer.

Comment: @dwkns I don't doubt statistical model will help, but it has to make sense.  I used the t-test to analyze A/B testing before, only to have the model tells me my A and B does not make a statistical difference -- which, i guess is good to know. From what I (just) read, analytical hierarchy process isn't to give hierarchy to the outcome, but to make one decision based on putting hierarchy of the criteria and opinion... (Which car should the family buy.. put these in hierarchy, subject and objective: cost, style, fuel, etc).  So not sure how you can use it, maybe you can elaborate?

Comment: Aran, you *can't* use data science to measure user experience. You can only use it to measure an aspect of a users experience. The efficiency of task completion or usability of a given feature for example. Or as @Novina says something like a A/B test. And I guess you could use a set of prioritised heuristics using some sort of statistical model to guide you but I guarantee what you'll end up with will be sub-optimal. Why, because humans are, well human and outside of extremes emotion is not well represented in statistical models.

Comment: ....cont. So sure in some cases statistical models can add information to the decision making process, but if you want to create great interfaces human judgement has to be the dominant factor.

Comment: @dwkns: My immediate perception is with you on "human-response can't necessarily be mathematicalize"... but I want statistical analysis on whether my immediate perception is accurate. ;)

Comment: I thought I made it clear that using statistical models are purely to aid one's  decision making process. A blog would elaborate a bit further :-? . Added a note to myself.

Comment: I am sorry if I am double-asking: 

Do you want to find a priority for your implementation on issues you FOUND or WILL FIND (impact on business value) or do you want to evaluate the efficiency of looking in a certain direction before putting effort in it? Or is it something completely different?

Comment: As @Jan alludes to there is ambiguity in your question. Usability can be analysed statistically. Ease of use is a subjective quality which is more of a qualitative rather than quantitive measure. And in either case both can only be factored into your design process after you have already designed and built something to test. Using other peoples statistics to help you create a design in the first place is generally not sensible.

Comment: ...cont So in that respect, yes, statistical modelling and even using a Analytical Hierarchy Process could be used to optimise a design and even to priorities what in the design should be addressed first. 

However I suspect that would probably only really be valuable when addressing marginal gains in large datasets. Amazon increasing checkout completion by 0.01% v increasing perception of ease of use (and therefore long term sales by 0.01%) are worth spending time analysing.

Comment: ...cont The vast majority of designs have so much low hanging fruit that simple judgment calls (guided by heretics and experience) are likely to deliver much better results.

Comment: @dwkns If you can measure an aspect of user experience, then sure collecting as many different measures will allow you to approximate the perceived or expected user experience? Better than just relying on someone's opinion don't you think?

Comment: @MichaelLai I'm not clear by what you mean. Again it depends on wether you mean to optimise an existing design or to guide the initial design process. Every project is different so using existing statistics (by their nature for a different project) would not be a sensible approach. However doing analysis of an existing design and using that data to influence future optimisations is. However I believe most experienced designers would use their judgement to decided design priorities rather than something like Analytical Hierarchy Process. Also judgment and opinion are very different things.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is no reason why AHP can't be used for making decisions in UX design to prioritize tasks or requirements, I think you'll find that the level of analysis required and the output generated isn't necessarily the answer that you want.

Instead, there are simple strategies or processes that will give you the high level buckets (e.g. [MoSCoW process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MoSCoW_method)) that allows you to narrow the focus and therefore the complexity of the analysis and decision that needs to be made.

I don't know of any examples or projects where this has been applied, but given that it is not too dissimilar to other methods I can imagine that it has been applied somewhere.

If the complexity of the analysis is prioritizing the tasks or requirements in the context of UX design only, then I think AHP might be an overkill. However, if it is about weighing UX considerations in the context of other business or technical constraints then you may consider more complex analysis processes.

Comment: Yes I agree for a manual or semi automated approach,  MoSCow is good at arriving at a decision . With a multi-criteria decision analysis tool such a AHP it would be possible to bring your considerations /criteria  onto an analysis model and use fuzzy logic to prioritise your considerations to achieve certain goals.  There are software packages and tools to help to do that.